# Generic parameter resolution without looking for super type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, variance

I'm creating a property mapper. I'd like to be able to specify an associative relationship between KProperty and it's value. I'd like to have something like that:

```kotlin
infix fun <TProperty> KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty>.to(that: TProperty) = Pair(this, that)
```

but for the following class:

```kotlin
interface Changeable
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Number, val salary: Double) : Changeable
```

when I declare potentially faulty map:

```kotlin
val entry = (Person::age to "9999") //String instead of Number
```

this type is resolved to:

```kotlin
Pair<KProperty1<out Changeable, Serializable>, Serializable>
```

While it looks all nice and compiles, this is dangerous in runtime. How can I restrict TProperty to be exactly the same type as KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty> without looking for super type (Serializable instead of Int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* an internal annotation [`@InputTypesOnly`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/86cabf3bb765c181797595123e4c0a3c074da432/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/internal/Annotations.kt#L37) that solves exactly this problem. It causes type inference to fail if the inferred type (like `Serializable`) is not any of the type parameters. However, you cannot use it for obvious reasons. Follow [KT-13198](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13198/Expose-OnlyInputTypes-annotation-to-allow-proper-checks-of-parameters-of-generic-methods-same-as-those-used-Collectioncontains), which is about making it public.

However, there seems to be a trick that you can do (I learned this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72669016/5133585)) - if you put the type you want "correctly" inferred (`TProperty`) into both a lambda parameter and lambda return position, then it does get "corretly" inferred.

```
infix fun <TProperty> KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty>.to(
    that: (TProperty) -> TProperty) =
    Pair(this, that(TODO()))

val entry = Person::age to { "" } // error
val entry = Person::age to { 1 } // ok
```

I guess by having `TProperty` in both positions, the compiler adds enough constraints for it to stay "fixed".

Of course, we have no instances of `TProperty` to pass to the `that` lambda, so a better idea would be to use the receiver's type `KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty>`:

```
infix fun <TProperty> KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty>.to(
    that: (KProperty1<out Changeable, TProperty>) -> TProperty) = 
    Pair(this, that(this))
```

Note that with this signature, `entry` would have a type of:

```
Pair<KProperty1<out Changeable, Number>, Number>
```

If you want

```
Pair<KProperty1<Person, Number>, Number>
```

instead, you should add another type parameter for the first type argument of `KProperty1` rather than using `out Changeable`:

```
infix fun <TReceiver: Changeable, TProperty> KProperty1<TReceiver, TProperty>.to(
    that: (KProperty1<TReceiver, TProperty>) -> TProperty) = 
    Pair(this, that(this))
```