Arguments of extension function with receiver of generic type
I would like to replace a set of extension functions like this:
fun Boolean.assertEquals(value: Boolean) = assertEquals(value, this)
fun Int.assertEquals(value: Int) = assertEquals(value, this)

with something generic like this:
fun <T> T.assertEquals(value: T) = assertEquals(value, this)

However, with this function compiler doesn't catch the type errors:
// compilation successful
"1".assertEquals(1)

I also found that if I introduce a middle class ...
class Assertable<T>(val value: T)
fun <T> Assertable<T>.assertEquals(value: T) = assertEquals(value, this.value)
fun <T> T.assert() = Assertable(this)

... then this already gives compile time error:
// compilation error
"1".assert().assertEquals(1)

Is there any Kotlin magic that allows to avoid middle class and catch wrong arguments in compile time?

There is an annotation for that, but it is internal. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73200426/5133585

What don't you like about Assertable, exactly?

Assertable makes the call longer than it could be. It is not that I don't like, but rather I am looking if this can be avoided.

And what are you trying to avoid is what I am asking for. So you want to avoid making the call longer?

I don’t think it’s possible because it would otherwise have no way of knowing when two things could not possibly be equal. We know that the String class (and many other classes) will return false if the compared item isn’t also a String. But for example, LinkedList and ArrayList do not have this behavior. One of them can be equal to one of the other class.

If you have only just a few of such functions and especially if they are for primitive types, then I say: don't overengineer this and keep multiple functions. It is a common thing in Java/Kotlin that we need to duplicate a function for each primitive type. If you mean you like to use this against any object, then as @Tenfour04 said, you shouldn't assume objects of different types cannot be equal.
