# How to enforce same generic type of covariant type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, covariance

I've got a mapper of following interface:

```kotlin
interface Mapper<From, To> {
    fun <T> addMapping(
        source: KProperty1<From, T>, 
        target: KProperty1<To, T>,
    )
}
```

I'd expect that calling this function would enforce the same type of both KProperties, but the following is allowed:

```kotlin
data class Source(val str: String)
data class Target(val int: Int)

val mapper: Mapper<Source, Target> = // ...
mapper.addMapping(Source::str, Target::int)
```

Where Kotlin infers the second property type to be `KProperty1<Target, {Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}>`

AFAIK this is caused by the covariance of the second type parameter: `KProperty1<T, out V>`. Is there a way to enforce exact type match between these two properties?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72668941/5133585). There are internal annotations that enforce this, .e.g `@OnlyInputTypes` and `@Exact`, and there are open tickets for making them public. See also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49194/Expose-kotlin.internal.Exact-or-some-other-mechanism-for-fixing-types.

Comment: @Sweeper that's a shame. It would make many APIs much more type safe. Thanks for the answer though