# Compile-time check for lambda type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, extension-function

I'm trying to create an extension function I can apply to collections similar to filter/map/etc. Typing due to generics is pretty loose and I want to be more strict. Is there anything I can do in Kotlin?

```kotlin
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filterIn(other: Collection<T>): List<T> {
    return this.filter { it in other }
}

inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.filterIn(other: Collection<R>, transform: (T) -> (R)): List<T> {
    return this.filter { transform(it) in other }
}
```

The following tests pass as expected:

```kotlin
listOf("1", "2", "3").filterIn(setOf("1", "2")) == listOf("1", "2")
listOf("1", "2", "3").filterIn(setOf(1, 2)) { it.toInt() } == listOf("1", "2")
```

The following tests also pass but I would ideally want them to fail at compile time:

```kotlin
listOf("1", "2", "3").filterIn(setOf(1, 2)) == emptyList<String>() // should know set not same type as list
listOf("1", "2", "3").filterIn(setOf(1, 2)) { it } == emptyList<String>() // should know function doesn't return same type as list
listOf("1", "2", "3").filterIn(setOf(1, 2)) { mapOf("foo" to "bar") } == emptyList<String>() // should know function doesn't return same type as list
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73200426/5133585 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/72668828/5133585 might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not officially supported as of Kotlin 1.9.22.

However, there is a hidden feature that does exactly this. We can enable it by annotating type parameters with `@kotlin.internal.Exact`. Unfortunately, as its name suggests, it is internal and we can't use it just like that. One way to use it is:

```kotlin
@Suppress("INVISIBLE_MEMBER", "INVISIBLE_REFERENCE")
inline fun <T> Iterable<@kotlin.internal.Exact T>.filterIn(other: Collection<T>): List<T> {
    return this.filter { it in other }
}

@Suppress("INVISIBLE_MEMBER", "INVISIBLE_REFERENCE")
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<@kotlin.internal.Exact T>.filterIn(other: Collection<R>, transform: (T) -> (@kotlin.internal.Exact R)): List<T> {
    return this.filter { transform(it) in other }
}
```

Of course, we don't have any guarantees it will work in future versions of Kotlin.

Comment: Nice, that works! Shame it's internal only for now, might use it if I see that it doesn't get removed with Kotlin 2.0 whenever that's out.